# "Достаточно далекая от нас страна": Is this kind of piled-up nominal phrase considered formal in Russian?

Tags: стилистика

> Поскольку Япония - достаточно далекая **от нас** страна, ...

In German, inserting a prepositional phrase like "от нас" into a nominal phrase in this manner is considered rather formal. What about in Russian? I wonder if in conversation I need to paraphrase it somehow in a more relaxed style?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82881/discussion-on-question-by-con-gras-tue-les-chiens-----).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, not at all.

Here's what would be considered formal:

> Поскольку Япония — страна достаточно от нас далекая, ...

It looks nothing like German, but there's cast-iron logic to the word order here. Just putting **страна** at the end when it's not the most informative word in the sentence is fairly relaxed.

**Достаточно далекая страна от нас* sounds un-Russian unless you specifically want to stress **от нас** (as opposed to it being remote from someone else).

If there's anything formal here, it's the use of **достаточно** instead of the more generic **довольно**. Think "fairly remote" vs. "quite remote".

Answer (score 4):

There's nothing specifically formal or colloquial in such usage - "от нас" in this context just indicates the relative distance  - from us to Japan. This can be equally used in official speech and in everyday conversation.

Answer (score 1):

This is only adding an extra clarification to the meaning of the phrase. For example, a Muscovite may say "Поскольку Япония - достаточно далекая **от нас** страна" in a conversation with someone from Vladivostok, but not from Saint-Petersburg or Sochi.

Answer (score 0):

Such an expression (despite widely used) usually reveals a speaker as a cautious person (if not a diplomat or mathematician) since *all* that stands behind **достаточно далёкий** (distant enough or even 'little enough') is just that Japan is **distant enough to use the word 'distant'** for it. Expressions with more sense are more clear: **относительно, сравнительно далёкий** (relatively or comparatively distant). **Достаточно** is used properly e. g. when it is followed by something, showing '*enough for what*', otherwise expressions with it only reveal unsophisticated speech *habits*.

Comment: The OP isn't asking about this)

Comment: indeed i've too noticed that most respondents missed or ignored the point

Comment: @БаянКупи-ка On a similar note: "Но главное, чтобы никто не догадывался о **связывающих нас** узах." Do you find this structure a little too formal to be used in conversation? Or is it perfectly standard register-wise?

Comment: @Con-gras-tue-les-chiens yes the phrase in bold is a bit stiff, more pertinent to formal style, in a normal language that would be expressed by a subordinate clause which is a characteristic feature of vernacular - **об узах, которые нас связывают**